# What is the difference between filing the screen with pixels and graphics like OpenGL?

Tags: graphics, pixel

I've just started looking to graphics tools and how it could be made to be faster without compromising performance and then this question came to mind: what is the difference of filling the screen pixels with some colors coordinated by some optimized code to deal with "graphics" versus the actual 2D/3D graphics tools such as OpenGL, Unity, etc.?

What I want to mean by that is the following: I was seeing this video about .kkrieger fps game that used only 96kB of memory. Of course it produced huge amount of need for CPU and GPU to perform well. But what if instead of compact size files, there was a way to actually do some nice graphics with great performance without a need for a very expensive CPU+GPU combo? Is that possible anyway?

Comment: The question seems unclear... Both way of rendering ultimately result in the same thing. Pixel drawn to your screen with a software often use the CPU and those in games are calculated with shaders, which are run on the GPU. The later one is more efficient at great scale and useless at when only filling the screen.

Comment: @FrédéricPerron in that sense, how come building geometric shapes is more efficient than filing pixels? Is there any "completion" algorithm that a defined rule is applied?

Comment: Actually, that's the whole point of shader. One shader (which is a program) is run for each point in a given shape. It computes de final position of the point on the screen. This is called the `vertex shader`. After, for each pixel between those vertices, or points, the pixel color is computed using the `fragment shader`. In that shader, you can compute anything really like lights and stuff really efficiently with a low memory because the graphic card hosts the necessary operations.

Comment: pixel access is more CPU side style and rendering geometry fast is GPU side job ... The difference is speed. The whole purpose of GPU is to accelerate the CPU side rendering. So on platforms where GPU is present is pointless to use CPU side rasterization as GPU can done that nativelly `many` times faster. However there are still platforms without GPU like MCUs and various control systems and there the pixel access and low level gfx kicks in ... Also rasterization is still used for other tasks like motion control etc and there the pixel access is still relevant.